# Reading stdin and make a string array

Tags: arrays

I am trying to read name from standard input and make a string array. But when empty line appears that also goes to the array which I don't want. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Read {
   public static void  main(String args []) throws IOException{
   BufferedReader reader =new BufferedReader(new inputStreamReader(System.in));
   String str;
   ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
   while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
      lines.add(str);
   }
   String[] linesArray = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);

   for (String input: linesArray){
      System.out.println(input);
   }
  }
}
```

INPUT:

```
John
Mike

dasy
egor
```

I debug it and I saw the array looks like :

```
[0] String .. "John"
[1] String .. "Mike"
[2] Striing.. ""
[3] String .. "dasy"
[4] String .. "egor"
[5] String .. ""
```

Can any one please help me to fix it?
Plus some reason I am not getting any output that means it is not terminating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the string lenght of str before adding lines like

```
while((str = reader.readLine()) != null){
     if str.lenght() > 0 {
       lines.add(str);
     }
 }
```

Comment: ok now there is no empty array but the last name is not appearing + the program not terminating to show output